# Get Photo from album is not working in MobileFirst using mobile browser simulator

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to run this code from phonegap so I can integrate it in my hybrid android application built with IBM MobileFirst.

The capture photo button is working perfectly(source: camera)

While the other buttons are not working at all.. I want to be able to get photo from my gallery or album...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>Capture Photo</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// Cordova is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
  // console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you should rely on the MBS for such things. Did you test your code in actual devices or simulators?

Comment: actually no .. but i think the error is in getphoto() function source: album or  library

Comment: i enabled java settings , the camera API is working well .. viewing photo from source: camera worked too so MBS is fine i believe.. @IdanAdar

Comment: 1) Please verify in an Android device. 2) Mention your MFP version and build number 3) If still failing, provide code that can be run end-to-end.

Comment: Waiting to hear back from you.

Comment: worked well on a real device (after installing the .apk) actually!! thanks @IdanAdar

Comment: Please write an answer or remove question so that the question won't be empty.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML in the question is not based on a Hybrid app generated by MobileFirst Platform Foundation; it is missing all sort of references that are required. I am not surprised this code does not run at all for you.

Create a MobileFirst app in MFP Studio. This app will have Cordova built-in. All you need to do next is to add the required code snippets related to the camera API from Cordova:

```
func wlCommonInit() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
   ...
   ...
```

The HTML should be placed in index.html of the application.
Also test in an actual device. Per the written by you in the comments - it will then work there.