# Camera with resizing functionalities cause file name change

Tags: android, cordova, camera, ibm-mobilefirst

For camera access, I am using mobilefirst 7.0 (worklight) camera feature containing target width and height property enabled.
Mobilefirst is using cordova at the end.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (uri) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(uri, function(fileEntry) { 
        fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

When I pick image from gallery and get file name from fileobj, I am getting file name as modified.jpg. I didn't get actual file name because it is giving me caching file name.

Is there any way to get actual file name?

If I didn't go for target width and height property, I get actual file name, but for file size re-sizing target width and height property is required.

I have found that updation of cordova can solve this problem, but I think that would be not possible in mobile first.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the cordova camera plugin version 2.0.0 Check out th camera plugin [release notes](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md) for more info on this.

This is the issue description in release notes - "Try to use realpath filename instead of default modified.jpg". Try updating your camera plugin to get away from the issue.Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't use any plugin for this. I can access camera directly navigator.camera.getPicture. Should I have to integrate camera plugin for this?

Comment: @parth.hirpara your question clearly states - "For camera access, I am using navigator camera plugin". Not sure whats the confusion. Of course, you should be using the plugin

Comment: Plugin was created as own but I did not use cordova plugin.

Comment: @parth.hirpara I really dont understand what you mean by created as own? Do you have camera plugin added already?

Comment: @parth.hirpara Check out this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851608/get-photo-from-album-is-not-working-in-mobilefirst-using-mobile-browser-simulato Mobilefirst still uses cordova plugin in the background.